On the Diophantine equation $2^a3^b + 4^c5^d = 2^b3^a + 4^d5^c$
In this year's team selection test to the international mathematical Olympiad in Japan, a interesting diophantine equation appeared as the final problem of the second day.

Find all quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ of positive integers, such that $2^a3^b + 4^c5^d = 2^b3^a + 4^d5^c.$

It is clear that those quadruples satisfying $a = b$ and $c = d$ are trivial solutions. How could I proceed? And is there any generalization of this problem?
Any advice is welcomed.
Also posted here.

It's considered very bad form to simulpost here and to MO.

@GerryMyerson Sorry for my bad behaviour but I reposted it in MO since I noticed some other posts had done the same thing.

@LastingHowling the usual process is to wait a few days before crossposting.

@YCor Got it. Sorry for my inappropriate post.

You can still delete your repost on MO.

By a positive integer, do you mean a number $z$ for which $z \ge 0$ or $z > 0$ (is zero allowed or not?)?

WLOG $a<b$. We quickly derive $2^{b-a}\equiv 3^{b-a} \bmod 5$, implying $b,a$ have the same parity. We also see $5^c\equiv 5^d \bmod 3$, implying $c,d$ have the same parity.

I almost completed my answer on MO but the question became removed. Are you still interested or solved it yourself?

@FedorPetrov I am so sorry about what is happening. I restored the question and could you please post it if you are convenient? I keep trying to solve it but failed till now. It would be great to read your idea.

Here are a few observations, perhaps they inspire someone else to a complete answer:
Let $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ be positive integers such that
$$2^a3^b + 4^c5^d = 2^b3^a + 4^d5^c.\tag{1}$$
Then also
$$2^a3^b-2^b3^a=2^{2d}5^c-2^{2c}5^d.\tag{2}$$
First note that $a=b$ if and only if $c=d$, and indeed for all positive integers $a$ and $c$ the quadruple $(a,a,c,c)$ is a solution. So suppose now that $a\neq b$ and $c\neq d$. Then if $(a,b,c,d)$ is a solution, also $(b,a,d,c)$ is a solution, so without loss of generality we may assume that $a<b$, and then also $d<c$ because
$$2^{2d}5^c-2^{2c}5^d=2^a3^b-2^b3^a>0.$$
Then comparing $2$-adic valuations shows that
\begin{eqnarray}
v_2(2^a3^b-2^b3^a)&=&a,\\
v_2(2^{2d}5^c-2^{2c}5^d)&=&2d,
\end{eqnarray}
and so we see that $a=2d$.  We saw that $d<c$ and $2d=a<b$ and so we can divide by $2^{2d}$ to get
$$3^b-2^{b-2d}3^{2d}=5^c-2^{2c-2d}5^d,$$
and then factoring out the common factors $3^{2d}$ and $5^d$ we find that
$$3^{2d}(3^{b-2d}-2^{b-2d})=5^d(5^{c-d}-4^{c-d}).\tag{3}$$
where clearly the left hand side is divisible by $3$, and the right hand side is divisible by $5$. We see that
$$5^{c-d}\equiv4^{c-d}\pmod{3}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad 3^{b-2d}\equiv2^{b-2d}\pmod{5},$$
from which it follows that $c\equiv d\pmod{2}$ and $b\equiv 2d\pmod{2}$. Set $B:=\tfrac{b-2d}{2}$ and $C:=\tfrac{c-d}{2}$ to get
$$3^{2d}(3^{2B}-2^{2B})=5^d(5^{2C}-4^{2C}).\tag{4}$$
This has the clear solution $(B,C,d)=(1,1,1)$, corresponding to the solution $(a,b,c,d)=(2,4,3,1)$ to equation $(1)$.
Because $3$ divides $5-(-4)=9$, by lifting the exponent we see that
$$v_3(5^{2C}-4^{2C})=v_3(5^{2C}-(-4)^{2C})=v_3(5-(-4))+v_3(2C)=v_3(C)+2,$$
where of course
$$v_3(5^{2C}-4^{2C})=v_3(5^d(5^{2C}-4^{2C}))=v_3(3^{2d}(3^{2B}-2^{2B}))=2d,$$
and so we see that $v_3(C)=2(d-1)$. Similarly, because $5$ divides $3-(-2)=5$, by lifting the exponent we see that
$$v_5(3^{2B}-2^{2B})=v_5(3^{2B}-(-2)^{2B})=v_5(3-(-2))+v_5(2B)=v_5(B)+1,$$
where again
$$v_5(3^{2B}-2^{2B})=v_5(3^{2d}(3^{2B}-2^{2B}))=v_5(5^d(5^{2C}-4^{2C}))=d,$$
and so we see that $v_5(B)=d-1$, and so $v_3(C)=2v_5(B)$. We can now write $B=5^{d-1}u$ and $C=9^{d-1}v$, with $u$ and $v$ positive integers coprime to $5$ and $3$, respectively, to get
$$3^{2d}\left(3^{2\cdot5^{d-1}u}-2^{2\cdot5^{d-1}u}\right)=5^d\left(5^{2\cdot9^{d-1}v}-4^{2\cdot9^{d-1}v}\right).\tag{5}$$
Now we see that the left hand side is divisible by $3^{2\cdot5^{d-1}}-2^{2\cdot5^{d-1}}$ and the right hand side is divisible by $5^{2\cdot9^{d-1}}-4^{2\cdot9^{d-1}}$.
For $d\geq2$ this shows that the left hand side is divisible by
$$3^{10}-2^{10}=5^2\times11\times211,$$
and the right hand side is divisible by
$$5^{18}-4^{18}=3^4\times7\times19\times61\times1459\times3907.$$
These numbers, and the number and size of their factors, grow quickly as $d$ increases. But I am unable to show that there are no further solutions.
